# I want to know how I can change this sentence to question

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I had a situation of being asked to bring the lastest mail that I got. But then I wanted to ask how old it can be to be accepted. So I tried to think how I can ask my wonder. Here is the my thought.

> It should be the mail that you got at least before 3 months from the day you ask for one.

At least before how many months should the mail that I got be?

Comment: Is the letter postmarked less than 3 months ago?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, it is confusing that way you've asked it.

Comment: I want to change first sentence to question.

Comment: The sentence that starts with 'It'

Comment: "Should it be... ?" It should be.

Comment: Thanks! If I say it should be, does it sound correct?

Comment: You question contains contradictions. First you say that only new mail will be accepted. Then you say that only old mail will be accepted. Please explain the situation. To whom will you bring the mail? What kind of mail? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just ask directly which mail the person wants.

> Which mail do you want?

and ask until you know which one to bring.

Comment: To sound less aggressive: `Which mail should I bring?` And you can add: `Please be more specific.`

Answer (score 0):

> Should I submit the mail for the last three months?

*The last three months* means *nearest to the present time*.

Comment: I was thinking to "Should I submit the mails of the last three months". Is the "of" correct ? ( I want to improve my knowledge about using prep.s. )

Comment: *For* denotes a period of time. You can't use *of* here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you living in the United States? Are you required to prove that you live at a particular address? Perhaps you are registering your children for school. If so, some possible forms of the question could be:

> How recent does the piece of mail have to be?
>   How old can the piece of mail be?

Some possible answers:

> It must be something which you received within the last three months.
>   It must be from within the last month.
>   It must be no more than two months old.